# Add class to specific element 10 at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add a class to all `.path` elements but 10 at a time.
I have the following code:

```
$(".path").each(function(i) {
    var e = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        e.addClass('show');
    }, 100);
});
```

this adds a class to each element 1 at a time but how could I add 10 at a time.

Comment: what?! you want to add the class 10 times?

Comment: _"10 at a time"_ ? What ? 10 classes ?

Comment: Pass an array of elements to your `setTimeout()`...

Comment: you mean checking if there is ten .path nodes and then adding the class?

Comment: adding a same class multiple time doesn't make any difference. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If yes, `e.addClass('show1 show2 show3 ......');`

Comment: Add a fiddle, it would be easier to understand the question.

Comment: What he wants is to add `show` class to 10 `.path` elements and then wait 100 milliseconds, and then add to another 10 of the remaining and so on.

Comment: The requirement is clear. OP has a large number of .path elements, and wants to add the .show class to the first ten elements. Then, after a delay, add .show to the next ten. Then delay, another ten. Etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn check http://stackoverflow.com/a/36793985/2209876

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by combining the [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) and normal `for` loop,

```
var elem = $(".path");
for(i=0;i<elem.length;i+=10) {
 setTimeout(function(i){
   elem.slice(i,i+10).addClass("show")
 }, 100 * i, i);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y6qxhtk4/2/)

Comment: Though this will work for sure, I think you should also provide a solution considering code provided by OP..

Comment: @RayonDabre - But the OP's code isn't suitable for this requirement. Using .each() doesn't work for ten at a time. Hence the question...

Comment: @nnnnnn Actually It had to be 10. That must be a typo. Correcting it now.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I just understood the question! My bad :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use `slice` method like this

```
var first10Elements = $(".path").slice(0,10);
first10Elements.addClass('show');
```

You can keep a counter `counter`

```
var counter = 0;
function addClass()
{
    if ( counter > $(".path").size() )
    {
       return false;
    }
    var first10Elements = $(".path").slice(counter,counter+10);
    first10Elements.addClass('show');
    counter = counter+10;
    setTimeout(function(){
        addClass();
    }, 100);
}
addClass();
```

This method will add class `show` to 10 `path` elements at a time and stop when all of them are done.

And you can generalize it like this

```
function addClass(currentClass, newClass, counter)
{
    $("." + currentClass ).slice(counter,counter+10).addClass( newClass );
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ( counter < $(".path").size() )
        {
           addClass(currentClass, newClass, counter+10);
        }
    }, 100);
}
addClass("path", "show", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this option. I think the user wants to add .show all the elements .path in simultaneous. But now, better explained in the comments.

```
//$(".path").addClass("show);
```

New option

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
            if($(".path:not(.show)").length == 0) {
            alert("Finish");
                  clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);      
      } else {
          $(".path:not(.show)").slice(0,10).addClass("show");
          console.log("Run");
      }
}, 300);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yosrc11u/4/

Comment: It is really not clear what the OP is asking and this answer doesn't help at all.

Comment: Is not clear.. I think the user wants to add .show all the elements .path in simultaneous -_-

Comment: I don't think so. Please read the comments by `nnnnnn`. I think that's what the user wants.

Comment: recently commented that :(

Comment: That's great! I like it. It is cleaner than what others have. If you could increase the time a little bit it would have good effect.

Comment: And this will run for ever and ever. Need to set a breaking condition for this.

Comment: check now @RajaprabhuAravindasamy